# How to edit retrieved wizard answer in Openerp wizard

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I happened to come a cross this Openerp wizard for the first time and also I got to know once you click on the "Done" button you can not edit what you have saved. 
What I need to do is make that wizard editable for some states once you retrieve  it.

Following is my call for the wizard and please help me with making it editable.

**xml call**

```
 <button name="action_call_questions" string="Start" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

**function**.

```
 def action_call_questions(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        """
        Open Browse Response wizard. if you select only survey_id then this wizard open with all response_ids and 
        if you select survey_id and response_id then open the particular response of the survey.
        """
        if context is None: context = {}
        record = self.read(cr, uid, ids, [])
        record = record and record[0] or {} 
        if record['response_id']:
            res_id = [(record.get('response_id') and record['response_id'][0])]
        else:
            sur_response_obj = self.pool.get('survey.response')
            res_id = sur_response_obj.search(cr, uid, [('survey_id', '=', record['survey_id'][0])])
        context.update({'active' : True,'survey_id' : record['survey_id'][0], 'response_id' : res_id, 'response_no' : 0})
        search_obj = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view')
        search_id = search_obj.search(cr,uid,[('model','=','survey.question.wiz'),('name','=','Survey Search')])
        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            "view_mode": 'form',
            'res_model': 'survey.question.wiz',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'search_view_id':search_id[0],
            'context' : context
         }
```